# Unsure how to add a object collection to a JTable

Tags: java, jdbc, jtable

i'm having a few problems in my attempts to pass a Object Collection to a JTable,

The issue is i'm not sure what i can do to to basically use the Object collection in my JTable

I had a look at this  but i'm not sure what i can do 
[link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Buildatablefromlistdataandcolumnnames.htm)

Below is the code i am currently using for the DAO and the Main class

[Object DAO](http://pastebin.com/WN06jYQt):

[Main Class](http://pastebin.com/3z4mWqP2):

Comment: Do you have a code example??  You're probably better off reading through [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), in particular [Creating a TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).  I'd also take a look at [AbstractTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html)

Comment: my current code is in the pastebin links, i'll take a look at the how to use tables thing though

Comment: If your code is too long to post in the forum, it's likely too long to ask volunteers to go through. Consider creating and posting a minimal compilable and runnable example, an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: duly noted.. although i was more asking for assistance on what to use, not really what i need to change to my current code, the code i have provided is merely reference to what i currently have

Comment: i've had a look and i think i would be better off using a JList not a JTable as i can make it simpler for my users

Answer (score 0):

> The TableModel interface defines the how the data can interact with the JTable. There are two classes that implement the TableModel interface - the DefaultTableModel and the AbstractTableModel. The AbstractTableModel implements the majority of the methods defined in the TableModel interface and leaves three methods (getRowCount, getColumnCount, getValueAt) which must be implemented by a subclass. It's the basis for any custom table model a programmer might create. The DefaultTableModel class is such an implementation. It is a subclass of the AbstractTableModel with the three methods implemented where the data is stored in **a Vector of Vectors**.
>
> By using your own custom table model built from the AbstractTableModel you can choose to store the data however you want to but you'll need to implement the methods that allow the data to interact with the JTable seamlessly. How many methods will depend on how much the JTable needs to manage the data. For a read-only JTable then the three default methods mentioned above are enough. But for a JTable that allows extensively editing (e.g., adding and removing rows and columns) then these methods will need to implemented to reflect the changes in the data that's been stored in the table model.

Courtesy - http://java.about.com/od/Creating-Tables/a/The-Jtable-Table-Model.htm